# Pagination replacing new search results with old ones when try to change page

Tags: php, pagination, laravel-5

I've added a ajax search box in app's home page. It works fine. But when i use the pagination after the new results shows up, pagination leads me to the old results. I'm not sure what I'm not doing right. So looking for expert's help to get a solution for it.

I've these in `routes` --

```
Route::get('/', 'BookmarkController@index');
Route::post('/', 'BookmarkController@search');
```

I've these in their controller -

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $tags_list = Tag::orderBy('tag', 'asc')->get();
    $bookmarks = Bookmark::orderBy('created_at','desc')->where('public', '1')->paginate(10);
    $bookmarks_all = Bookmark::orderBy('created_at','desc')->where('public', '1')->get();
    return view('welcome')->with('bookmark', $bookmarks)->with('tags_list', $tags_list)->with('bookmarks_all', $bookmarks_all);
}

public function search(Request $request){
    $search_value = $_POST['search'];

    $bookmarks = Bookmark::orderBy('created_at','desc')->where('public', '1')->where('title', 'rlike', $search_value)->orwhere('description', 'rlike', $search_value)->orwhere('contents', 'rlike', $search_value)->orwhere('tags', 'rlike', $search_value)->paginate(10);
    return view('public_bookmarks')->with('bookmark', $bookmarks);
}
```

In `welcome.blade.php`

```
<div class="container content-container">
<div class="row ">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="page-header">
            <div class="row">
                <span class="title col-sm-8">Recent Bookmarks</span>
                <form id="demo-2" class="search-form col-sm-4" method="post">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <!-- <input id="search" class="form-control" onkeyup="search_data(this.value, 'result');" placeholder="Search" name="search" value="" type="text"> -->
                        <input id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search" value="" type="text">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="search-btn" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function() {
                            $('#search-btn').click(function(){
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: '/',
                                    type: "post",
                                    data: {'search':$('input[name=search]').val(), '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val()},
                                    success: function(data){
                                        $('#search-results').html(data);
                                    },

                                    error: function (data) {
                                        console.log('Error on Article extracting');
                                        console.log(data);
                                    }
                                }); 
                            });
                        });
                    </script>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9" id="search-results">

        @include ('public_bookmarks')
    </div>
</div>
```

In `public_bookmars.blade.php`

```
@if (count($bookmark) > 0)
<div class="row card-row">
@foreach ($bookmark as $bookmark_single)
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 card-parent" data-col="col-sm-4">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-part1">
                <div class="img-card">
                    <img src="{{$bookmark_single->thumbnail}}" />
                </div>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <h4 class="card-title">
                        {{ $bookmark_single->title }}
                    </h4>
                    <div class="card-desc">
                        {{ str_limit($bookmark_single->description, $limit = 50, $end = ' [...]') }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-read-more">
                    <p><?php   $tags = $bookmark_single->tags;
                        $tag_list = explode(',', $tags); ?>
                        @foreach ($tag_list as $tag)
                            <a href="/tag/{{$tag}}" class="label label-primary">{{$tag}}</a>
                        @endforeach
                    </p>
                    <p class="card-user">- &nbsp;<a href="/user/{{ $bookmark_single->bookmarker }}">{{ $bookmark_single->bookmarker }}</a></p>
                    <a class="v-link" target="_blank" href="{{ $bookmark_single->url }}">Visit the link</a>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-circle btn-lg btn-read-more"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
            </div>

            <div class="card-part2 col-xs-0">
                {{ print $bookmark_single->contents }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
</div>
{{ $bookmark->links() }}
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flash()` method to achieve this. [Old Input](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#old-input)
In your `search()` method add `$request->flash()`. This will flash the current inputs in the session.
And, next time you want retrieve it by `$request->old('search');`
Here's the complete `search()` method:

```
public function search(Request $request){
    $search_value = $_POST['search']; //assign the current value of search field
    if(!$search_value) //check if current value is not null, means this is new search or previous one
{   
    $search_value = $request->old('search'); //If search_value is null use the old value
    $request->search = $request->old('search'); //add the old value to current request so that it can be flashed
}

    $bookmarks = Bookmark::orderBy('created_at','desc')->where('public', '1')->where('title', 'rlike', $search_value)->orwhere('description', 'rlike', $search_value)->orwhere('contents', 'rlike', $search_value)->orwhere('tags', 'rlike', $search_value)->paginate(10);

    $request->flash(); //adding this request's search value to the session
    return view('public_bookmarks')->with('bookmark', $bookmarks);
}
```

### Update:

```
public function search(Request $request){
    //$search_value = $_POST['search']; change this to use $request
    $search_value = $request->search;

    $bookmarks = Bookmark::orderBy('created_at','desc')->where('public', '1')->where('title', 'rlike', $search_value)->orwhere('description', 'rlike', $search_value)->orwhere('contents', 'rlike', $search_value)->orwhere('tags', 'rlike', $search_value)->paginate(10);

    return view('public_bookmarks')->with('bookmark', $bookmarks)->withInput($request->only('search')); // flashed input to the view
}
```

Now, in your view you can get the value with `old()` method:

```
{{ $bookmark->appends(['search' => old('search')])->links()}}
```

### Update 2:

change your ajax call to use get method and point it to new address:

```
type: "get",
url: '/search'
```

Add a route to handle search request as a get method:

```
Route::get('/search', 'BookmarkController@search');
```

In your `search()` method use `$request` to get the search value:

```
$search_value = $request->search;
```

Comment: what about passing the argument to view ? will the update the answer

Comment: sorry, I din't notice there are 2 views. BTW, is it okay to get search value by GET method ?

Comment: yeah i guess, as long as i've the search results working.

Comment: @XahedKamal don't you think search route should be `get` rather than `post`. Cause, when I will click the next button that would be a get call

Comment: yes. but as i'm a newb on PHP and Laravel, i wasnt getting it successfully with get method. so i used post method that i found online in an example. So, if you can show me how to do it using 'get' would be very thankful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120944/discussion-between-jaysingkar-and-xahed-kamal).